# Subquery returning number rows

Tags: sql, count, sum

Have two tables: banks and branches.

Banks has: **bank_name**[red, blue, green,] **bank_ID**[1, 2 ,3]
Branches: **bank_ID**[1, 1, 2, 3], **branch_name**[wright, james, will, phil]

I need to **return the bank_name with more branches**, and it's number.

Is it possible to do it with a subquery? Thanks!

---

Edit for the answer:

SELECT ban.bank_name, COUNT(bra.branch_name)

FROM branches bra NATURAL JOIN banks ban

GROUP BY bank_name

HAVING COUNT(bra.branch_name)=(SELECT MAX(COUNT(branch_name))
                FROM branches
                GROUP BY bank_id);

I was having problems with the natural join, and how the subquery affects it.

Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT b.bank_id, COUNT(*)
FROM 
    bank b
        LEFT JOIN branches br ON br.bank_ID = b.bank_ID
GROUP BY b.bank_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68af9/3

Comment: Works like a charm, except for the 'limit 1' part. Thanks! But is it possible to do it with a subquery?